# How to create a third signature for document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I currently have a document that gets signed by two different users, I then need to go back through and get a third signature however on well I call the API to create the tab I get the following error:

```
Error calling CreateTabs: {
"errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
"message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. 
Recipient not in state that allows correction."
}
```

I'm assuming this means the envelope has been closed or can't be edited anymore? How would I go about changing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the envelope has reached the `completed` state then no further changes are allowed.

If you want to change the envelope based on what a signer does or doesn't do, then you need to

1. stop further processing after that signer
2. make your updates (add recipients, set tab values, etc)
3. resume processing

You can stop processing by including a dummy signing recipient. A fake embedded signer can be used if you're sending the envelope programmatically. If you're sending the envelope from a template or NDSE, you can use a certified copy recipient with an email that will be a black hole. (An email that auto-responds may enable the envelope to continue its routing.)

Resume processing by deleting the dummy recipient.

### Making updates

1. Call [EnvelopeLocks::create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/create)
2. Use the response's `lockToken` in your subsequent calls that change the envelope. Do this by adding an `X-DocuSign-Edit` header to the subsequent API calls.
3. When you're done making the updates, delete the fake recipient.
4. And delete the lock by using [EnvelopeLocks::delete](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/delete)

Example:

```
let lock_request = {
    lockDurationInSeconds: lock_duration,
    lockedByApp: "My app name",
    lockType: "edit"
}
let url = `${api_base_url}/accounts/${account_id}/envelopes/${envelope_id}/lock`;
return rp.post(url, {
    auth: {bearer: sender_access_token},
    body: lock_request,
    json: true
    })
})
.then((result) => {
  // Save the lock token and lock header
  lock_token = result.lockToken;
  lock_header = {'X-DocuSign-Edit': JSON.stringify({
        LockToken: lock_token,
        LockDurationInSeconds: lock_duration
        })}
})
```